# Integer Finder Issue

Tags: python, random

I am trying to make a function that finds the number you want with this code:

```
def get(x):
    y=1
    while (x/y != 1):
        y= y+1
    return y
```

But it keeps giving me one half of the answer + 1. Like, if I put in 6 it gives me 4, and if i put in 500 it gives me 251.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that it is doing integer division.  So, `6/4` evaluates to 1.  (In python3, true division would kick in and I think your test would work)

The best way to fix this would be to do something like:

```
while x != y:
    ...
```

And of course, these tests should really only be done using integers...once you pass a floating point number in, it's hard to say what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are looking for -

```
 def get(x):
     y=1.0
     while (x/y != 1):
             print y, x
             y= y+1
     return y
```

try below function call -

```
>>> get(5.0)
```

1 and 1.0 is does the trick. Check out the python documentation for more understanding!